# How to use speech to text component in Angular

Tags: angular

## Issue

In my configuration speech to text component is working fine in localhost but not in server deployed url.

**Are there  any permissions should be given from the server side?** when the setting is changed to allow "url" to use the microphone, It is switching back to continue to block this url. kindly someone please tell me how I can resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

I am also working on speech to text using speech recognition service for voice search. You can check the below link for reference.

https://github.com/fossasia/loklak_search/tree/master